# Using Storyboard mode and valueBox

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I have not been able to utilize the `valueBox` function in the flexdashboard storyboard mode. As the `valueBox` keeps appearing as a single box, instead of separate boxes. Did you manage to solve this problem? See screenshot below:

[image]

The code that I have written in the rmarkdown file is as follows:

````
---
title: "Childcare"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    social: menu
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
packages <- c("flexdashboard", "shiny", "jsonlite", "maptools", "ggplot2",
              "tidyr", "dplyr", "purrr", "leaflet", "plotly", "data.table",
              "rjson", "maptools", "reshape", "plyr", "reshape2")

for (p in packages) {
  # 'require' checks whether package exists and returns TRUE or FALSE
  if (!require(p, character.only = T)) {
    install.packages(p)
  }
  library(p, character.only = T)
}

# Loading the data
raw_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON("childcare_dataset.json", flatten=FALSE)
raw_data_flatten <- flatten(raw_data)
raw_data_df <- raw_data_flatten$records

raw_data_pg <- dplyr::filter(raw_data_df, raw_data_df$pg_vacancy!="na")
raw_data_n1 <- dplyr::filter(raw_data_df, raw_data_df$n1_vacancy!="na")
raw_data_n2 <- dplyr::filter(raw_data_df, raw_data_df$n2_vacancy!="na")
raw_data_k1 <- dplyr::filter(raw_data_df, raw_data_df$k1_vacancy!="na")
raw_data_k2 <- dplyr::filter(raw_data_df, raw_data_df$k2_vacancy!="na")

```

### What is the high-level overview of the childcare industry in Singapore?
```{r}
valueBox(length(raw_data_df), caption = "Total childcare facilities", icon="fa-random")
valueBox(42, caption = "N1 - No vacancy rate (%)", icon="fa-thumbs-down")

```
````

Comment: You'll need to provide some minimal code example to get any help.